# What is a $\psi_2$ random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In a paper I am reading there is the following statement:

> Let $u \in N_\epsilon$. We want a concentration inequality for $|n^{-1} \sum \langle u, X \rangle^2 - 1|$. We know that $\langle u, X \rangle$ is a $\psi_2$ random variable thus, $\langle u, X \rangle^2$ is a $\psi_1$ random variable...

What are $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ random variables?

The quote is found at the bottom of page 1 here: http://perso-math.univ-mlv.fr/users/banach/Fallschool2009/notes/L2009BasicToolsEmpiricalProcessesTheoryAppliedCompressSensing.chaining.pdf

Comment: It would be great to provide a link to the paper. I would assume that it is supposed to be square integrable ($\psi_2$) and integrable $\psi_1$, but this notion is nonstandard.

Comment: You can see the definition of $\psi_2$ r.v. on the same page, i.e. those are random variables such that $(u, X)$ has subgaussian tails for any $u \in S^{d-1}$. I suppose that $\psi_1$ random variables are those that have exponential tails, i.e. r.v. $X$ that satisfy $\mathbb{P}(\left \lvert(u,X) \right \rvert > t) \le 2 \exp(-ct)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is supposed to be the Euclidian scalar product. However, it is not defined and nonstandard, but would make sense by substituting $t$ with $\sqrt{t}$ for a $\psi_2$ r.v.